# What do i need to start reverse engineering?

Tags: iphone, reverse-engineering

I want to know what should i learn to become a reverse engineer?..Like Geohot i want to be able to revese engineer ps3 and iphone to make jailbreaks ..:D

Comment: The things you are asking are pretty broad, and not something that can be learned overnight.  Perhaps you should start reading the answers in questions like [What does jailbreak do to the iPhone technically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668867/what-does-jailbreak-do-to-the-iphone-technically).  Also, the PS3 encryption crack required quite a bit of knowledge about the hardware itself, along with some knowledge of how public key encryption works.  In other words: good luck trying to match the exploits of these folks.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend this book: [Reversing - Secrets of Reverse Engineering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764574817)

Answer (score -1):

You need a tool to reverse engineer binaries , for instance [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) for windows apps(c/c++).